# "Stack Exchange Year in Review 2016" misses the site design for Software Recommendations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog

The blog post [*Stack Exchange Year in Review 2016*](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/year-in-review-2016/) currently says:

> Once again, our designers amaze with their thoughtful site designs. They produced twelve more last year:
>
> - Aviation
> - Blender
> - Computer Science
> - Cryptography
> - Emacs
> - English Language Learners
> - Japanese
> - Magento
> - Music
> - Puzzling
> - Signal Processing
> - Worldbuilding

The design for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) was created, or at least finished/published, in 2016, too:

- [Software Recommendations New Site Design](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511/60) (2016-04-18)
- [New Site Design!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/60) (2016-04-22)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep. I missed it for reasons that I don't understand. They were in the list the designers were working from. I must have just missed the line as I was writing it up.

I also messed up a link and Quantitative Finance didn't show up in my query of graduated sites. So I [submitted an edit](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/267) to the blog repository. Should be fixed a bit later after the blog is built out.

Comment: How long would it typically take to update the post? Your edit doesn’t seem to be public yet.